# Why Isn't The html Element 100% Height By Default?

Tags: html, css, layout, height

Are there any situations where you wouldn't want the `html` element to take up the full height of the window? Why isn't it `100%` height by default?

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Update] I changed the title and removed reference to the `body` tag as I'm really interested in the `html` tag.

[Update] Just to clarify for the pedants, I appreciate the decision was made in the dawn of internet time and the world will probably end if the default value is ever changed. I would like to know if there is any case or situation where setting the `html` element's height to a value other than `100%` or not setting it to `100%` would serve any practical purpose. Should everyone in the world just set it to 100% and forget about it or are there any edge cases where this would cause issues?

Comment: There may or may not be situations, this is more a question of personal preferences, I think. Should a document have full height when it's content does not require that? There is no technical answer to that.

Comment: having anything less than html 100% limits yourself.  You can have divs that have limited height within the html tag, so unless you're sure you'll never want a full page ...I would keep height 100%

Comment: So, this is an subjective, and opinion-based, discussion, then? And, basically, the answer is going to be 'yes, sometimes, even if only rarely.'

Comment: @DavidThomas If it's opinion-based or subjective then I'm sure you'll have no problem giving me a single situation where you wouldn't want the html element to be 100% high.

Comment: @Pedr - Unless one was party to a private discussion of the time when it was decided, the answer to this is unknowable. But it doesn't matter, it is what it is, and can't be changed now because there are web pages that assume that the height will be `auto`, and would break if browsers defaulted differently.

Comment: @Alohci I think that's just a pedantic response. I'm interested in whether there are any cases where a hight other than 100% is useful or practical.

Comment: It's useful when the document won't fit in the window without scrolling.

Comment: @Quentin Please can you explain what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the application. It might be a bad idea depending on what you want, if you want the body to be smaller than the full height then yes.